# output changes while appending dictionary data into list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-extraction

I have a dictionary containing data in a certain format. When I am printing the dictionaries individually,  it is printing the data correctly but when I am adding all dictionaries into a list and then printing the list, it is printing wrong output. May I know the solution to this problem?

my code:

```
import glob
import os
list_for_dictionary = []
list_for_dictionary_2 = []

data_location = 'D:\\sample_data'  # folder containing all the data
for root, directories, files in os.walk(data_location):
    for directory in directories:
        loc = (data_location + '/' + directory + '/*')
        all_files = glob.glob(loc)
        for filename in all_files:
            list_for_dictionary.clear()
            f = open(filename) 
            for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                dictionary = {"fileLine": line.strip(), "lineNumber": int(line_number), "fileName": filename.split("\\")[-1]}
                list_for_dictionary.append(dictionary)

            dictionary_2={"collection":[], "documentName":filename.split("\\")[-1],"returnId":0,"docData":{"Matches":list_for_dictionary}}
            print(dictionary_2)
            list_for_dictionary_2.append(dictionary_2)
print(list_for_dictionary_2)
```

Expected output:

```
[{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: John', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 24 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}]}}
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample2.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Matthews', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample2.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 32 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample2.txt'}]}}
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample3.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Alisa', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample3.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 40 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample3.txt'}]}}
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample4.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Jacob', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 60 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}]}}]
```

My output:

```
[{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Jacob', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 60 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}]}},
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample2.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Jacob', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 60 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}]}}, 
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample3.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Jacob', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 60 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}]}}, 
{'collection': [], 'documentName': 'sample4.txt', 'returnId': 0, 'docData': {'Matches': [{'fileLine': 'Name of Person: Jacob', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}, {'fileLine': 'Age: 60 years', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample4.txt'}]}}]
```

Comment: It looks like you are walking through the file, but not closing it. This may cause some unexpected behavior. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. Pay attention to the part about using a with statement.

Comment: Thanks @MarcWagner . I checked but the error is still there even after adding f.close()

Comment: Is there a way to get this solved?

Comment: please post the contents of your sample.txt file(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a reference error. You are doing `"docData":"Matches":list_for_dictionary}}`, and then overwriting `list_for_dictionary` in subsequent loops.

Initialize a new `list_for_dictionary = []`, instead of clearing `list_for_dictionary.clear()`

```
import glob
import os
list_for_dictionary = []
list_for_dictionary_2 = []

data_location = 'D:\\sample_data'  # folder containing all the data
for root, directories, files in os.walk(data_location):
    for directory in directories:
        loc = (data_location + '/' + directory + '/*')
        all_files = glob.glob(loc)
        for filename in all_files:
            list_for_dictionary = []
            f = open(filename) 
            for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                dictionary = {"fileLine": line.strip(), "lineNumber": int(line_number), "fileName": filename.split("\\")[-1]}
                list_for_dictionary.append(dictionary)

            dictionary_2={"collection":[], "documentName":filename.split("\\")[-1],"returnId":0,"docData":{"Matches":list_for_dictionary}}
            print(dictionary_2)
            list_for_dictionary_2.append(dictionary_2)
print(list_for_dictionary_2)
```